# How to output correct result for multiple query

Tags: php, output

In query I have multiple output for price and p

For example

```
 $price = 100;
 $p = 7;
 $price = 50;
 $p = 3;
 $price = 200;
 $p = 2;
 $price = 10;
 $p = 10;
 $price += $price * $p;
 echo $price;
```

How to calculate each `$price` according to each `$p`?

Comment: Your Values do not appear as you have written them. They will be in an array. Can you give a var_dump() or print_r() of your actual output of your query?

Comment: Listen to Tim, and edit your question.  Then you will receive the highest quality answers.  If fact, this is probably best solved via sql.  Show us your table info and query.

Comment: Perhaps you can derive some inspiration from this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29437462/2943403

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Optionally, if you store values in array

```
function countTotal($price, $p) {
    return $price * $p; 
}

$price = [100, 200, 300];
$p = [1, 1.5, 2];

$totalArray = array_map('countTotal', $price, $p);
echo array_sum($totalArray);
```

Comment: The OP is probably iterating a resultset, so using a separate iterating function is ill-advised.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 $total = '';

 $price = 100;
 $p = 7;
 $total += $price*$p; // $total = 700
 $price = 50;
 $p = 3;
 $total += $price*$p; // $total = 850
 $price = 200;
 $p = 2;
 $total += $price*$p; // $total = 1250
 $price = 10;
 $p = 10;
 $total += $price*$p; // $total = 1350
 echo $total;
```

Comment: May you please add some explanation?

Comment: Every time $total multiply ($price*$p) and add into $total. so in first step $total = 700 then next $total = ($price*$p) = 150 and $total = 150 +700 = 850 and so on.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks all for your impact this fix my error example

```
 $price = "100";
 $p = "2";
 $price = "200";
 $p = "2";
 $price = "50";
 $p = "4";
 $price = "400";
 $p = "2";
 $price = $price * $p;
 $price = $price + $price;
 echo "$price";
```

Comment: We are happy to hear that your issue is eliminated.  Now, please think of SO and others.   Please add the info that I requested so that we can show the professional-grade / best practice solution for your task that leverages the greatness of sql.  We will not onlt teach you, but countless future readers.

Comment: if that is your actual code then that will never work... You are getting 400 * 2 = 800 then adding 800 to itself to get 1600. Which just happens to correspond to your values by shear accident... So again , if that is your code, it is very wrong.